# How do I debug scripts in the Chrome dev console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I used to just open the Scripts tab, but that has vanished. I know only have a Sources tab, and I cannot find my pages own script anywhere there. how do I open the script debugging window for a script local to my page, i.e. not in a .js file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scripts tab was renamed to Sources.  If you don't see your source files, click the little rectangle with a trangle in the top left corner, and a sidebar will open up, with two tabs "Sources" and "Content scripts". You can make this sidebar permanent by then clicking on the rectangle to the right of "Content scripts".

Comment: The scripts node under my page there only gives me garbled minified looking script.

Comment: Click on the `{}` tool in the bottom toolbar to format the scripts nicely. Or use non-minified scripts.

Comment: It works under the html tab in the tree as well, I just couldn't get a breakpoint to work and assumed I was wrong. Thanks.